# Emacs tramp, version control and toggle-read-only

Tags: emacs, emacs24

When using emacs 24 w/tramp on remotely RCS-controlled files, the toggle-read-only function (^X^Q) does not issue the usual "This file is under version control, blah, blah". Instead it flips the read-only permissions *without* checking out the file. This is catastrophic, as the next checkout will overwrite changes etc.

How do I get the standard behavour?
Cheers,
alf

*Edit* I tried

```
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-q" 'vc-toggle-read-only)
```

which does not really address the issue (the desired behaviour was removed).

To clarify: I want to have the version control warning when editing remote files - I currently get nothing.

Comment: Voting to reopen as Emacs and RCS are definitely "software tools commonly used by programmers" as mentioned in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Voting to reopen. As expected noone  in SuperUser shows much love for emacs/RCS, which, AFAIK are primarily programmers' tool.

Comment: Please roll back your edit and post the solution aa an answer and accept it. That way, this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [phils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324105/phils) suggestion above, pulled a copy of vc-toogle-readonly, renamed it to avoid clashes, dropped it into site-lisp, byte compiled it, and loaded it from .emacs:
(load-library "old-toggle-readonly")
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-q" 'old-toggle-read-only)

Works a charm.

Answer (score 4):

You can type <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> to check out the file.

If you want to keep using <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd> for that, follow this advice from the `NEWS.22` file:

> The key C-x C-q only changes the read-only state of the buffer
>   (toggle-read-only).  It no longer checks files in or out.
>
> We made this change because we held a poll and found that many users
>   were unhappy with the previous behavior.  If you do prefer this
>   behavior, you can bind `vc-toggle-read-only` to `C-x C-q` in your
>   `.emacs` file:
>
> ```
> (global-set-key "\C-x\C-q" 'vc-toggle-read-only)
> ```
>
> The function `vc-toggle-read-only` will continue to exist.

Comment: Not really my gripe. The problem I have happens while editing *under tramp*. In that condition ^X^Q flips the RO flag/permission and says nothing. I know I should be using ^Xvv, but ^X^Q is is hardwired and happens a lot: if the file is local I get a warning, if it's remote I get bubke - I want the warning always. The fix you suggest does not appear to do this - @least, not under tramp.

Comment: It looks like this behaviour has now been removed. In Emacs 24.1 `vc-toggle-read-only` was made into an obsolete alias for `toggle-read-only`; and in Emacs 24.3 the latter was made into an obsolete alias for `read-only-mode`. I don't know if the old behaviour survives anywhere in the current release. You may need to grab a copy of the old function (which should exist in Emacs 23), and add it to your init file.